# Updating the complete dynamodb table with new index

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am using dynamo db having around 15000 items. Each item has 4 indexes "url","date","html_data","org". I added one more index named "base_url" to this table.

Here the index "url" contains links of websites like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask , https://www.goal.com/en/news/neville-calls-man-utd-bunch-of-whingebags-ronaldo-seen/blt71f0824c3e8eaf1e etc.

and I need to update the new index "base_url" with the base urls of links present in index "url".

Here I am referring base url like https://stackoverflow.com/ , https://www.goal.com/

**I can update each of these individually but how can it be done for the complete 15000 items.** I found there is batchwrite item but didnt find anything like batchupdate.

I am using python boto3 for doing this.

```
response = table.get_item(
    Key={
        'url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask',
        "date" : "2021-12-28"
    }
)
item = response['Item']
print(item)
```

and

```
table.update_item(
    Key={
        'url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask',
        "date" : "2021-12-28"
    },
    UpdateExpression='SET base_url = :val1',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':val1': "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    }
)
```

Base url can be obtained using

```
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
print(requests.urllib3.util.parse_url(url)).path)
```

Answer (score 0):

use [awswrangler](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) to insert your data either as a dataframe using [put_df](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.dynamodb.put_df.html#awswrangler.dynamodb.put_df) or a list of dict using [put_items](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.dynamodb.put_items.html#awswrangler.dynamodb.put_items)